# webpack doesn't want to load normilize.css

Tags: css, webpack

I decided to try webpack recently and, basically, I have two style files for an app - style.css and normilize. But there's a problem - whenever I try to compile it with webpack it throws error:

```
 ERROR in C:/Users/Man/~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./css/normalize.css
C:\Users\Man\Desktop\work\js_tr\css\normalize.css:59:29: Unknown word
  display: inline-block; // 1
  vertical-align: baseline; // 2
                            ^
}

ERROR in C:/Users/Man/~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./css/normalize.css
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at new Input (C:\Users\Man\node_modules\css-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:31:23)
    at parse (C:\Users\Man\node_modules\css-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:22:17)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\Man\node_modules\css-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:61:24)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\Man\node_modules\css-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:34:16)
    at processCss (C:\Users\Man\node_modules\css-loader\lib\processCss.js:188:11)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\Users\Man\node_modules\css-loader\lib\loader.js:24:2)
 @ ./css/normalize.css 4:14-131
```

What might it be? How should I load normilize.css with webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS there is not `//` comments. Single line comments starts with `/*` and ends with `*/`. So, you need to replace your `normalize.css` with [this one](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.0.0/normalize.css).

Comment: Thanks, I've been using less instead of plain css, so I picked the file up from bootsrap's repo probably

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem, and it seems that i was somehow running the style-loader more than once, i removed all traces of it from my webpack config, and just did `require('style.css');` and it just loaded the css instead of throwing cryptic Unknown word errors.